# Как определить, что в ячейке находится формула, а не константа без помощи макросов?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть ячейка в которую пользователь обязательно должен ввести формулу, а не константу.
Как узнать формула ли в этой ячейке?

Способ отсюда:
http://www.excel-vba.ru/chto-umeet-excel/kak-uznat-est-li-formula-v-yachejke/
не подходит ввиду его ограниченности.

Как это сделать при помощи VBA я знаю, но мне это не подходит.

---

**UPD**
Для Excel 2013+ решение найдено:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/444446/481
Теперь интересует- возможно ли это в менее новых версиях Excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробовал в Excel2013 все сработало. И так как я сделал:

1. Выберем ячейку `A1`
2. Из меню выберем ДАННЫЕ / Работа с Данными / Проверка данных / Проверка данных...
3. Параметры / Тип данных / Другой
4. В поле формула вводим `=ЕФОРМУЛА(A1)`
5. OK

теперь когда хотим вводит значение дает ошибку. Когда вводим формулу нормально работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ верный. У меня excel 2003 -_-

Comment: @ReinRaus 2003? Это же 12 лет назад было. Винда XP, .NET только появился, 2-я матрица еще не вышла. И Скрепка еще жива! :(

Comment: @ReinRaus Спасибо. Если ответ правильный, отмете как правильный. Другим тоже может понадобится.

Comment: @PashaPash ну я не совсем правильно выразился :-) У меня- Open Office, а вот на работе 2003 :)

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev я обязательно приму Ваш ответ, если он будет лучшим из всех, но пока я не спешу. Не переживайте, я постоянно на сайте- не пропаду и не забуду.

Answer (score 2):

Для версий старше *Exel-2013* такого функционала (без использования VBA), к сожалению, нет.
Но вариант есть - использование **макрофункций**.

Не VBA, но макросы должны быть разрешены. На листе не используются, но применимы в именах. 
С помощью функции *ПОЛУЧИТЬ.ЯЧЕЙКУ* можно определить содержимое ячейки, ее адрес, заливку...

***Ctrl+F3*** - мы в *Диспетчере_имен*. Создать имя (пусть будет "тестформула"), в поле *Диапазон* вписать формулу:

```
 =ПОЛУЧИТЬ.ЯЧЕЙКУ(6;Лист1!$A$1)
```

На листе в любой ячейке:

```
=тестформула
```

Если в ячейке *А1* константа, результат - константа, если формула - отобразится формула. А что такое формула? Текст, который начинается знаком "=". Отлично! Можно научиться определять, что находится в *А1*:

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЛЕВСИМВ(тестформула)="=";"формула";"значение")
```

' ---------------

Чем это может помочь при контроле вводимых данных?

Имя у нас уже есть. Доработаем:

```
=ЛЕВСИМВ(ПОЛУЧИТЬ.ЯЧЕЙКУ(6;Лист1!$A$1)="="
```

В ссылке можно убрать закрепление строки - имя будет работать для ячеек столбца, если убрать закрепление столбца - имя действительно для строки.

Пишем в *C1*:

```
=тестформула
```

В проверке данных ячейки *А1*:

```
=C1
```

Порядок, получили замену для ЕФОРМУЛА :)